# Is the category of spherical fusion categories regular? (i.e. is image factorisation possible?)

Tags: ct.category-theory, fusion-categories

Consider the category where objects are strict spherical fusion categories and morphisms are strict spherical functors (preserving cups and caps). I am wondering whether there is some kind of image factorisation possible in this category, similar to finite groups, where every homomorphism can be written as a composition of an epimorphism and a monomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean functors up to equivalence?  Otherwise it's a 2-category, not a category.

Comment: Is the composite of two spherical functors not spherical again? (I'm not referring to spherical fusion cats, bimodule cats and module functors here.) Also I don't know when to call two functors equivalent.

Comment: There's a 2-category of tensor categories, tensor functors, and tensor natural transformations.  You're talking about a 1-category, so do you mean tensor functors up to natural isomorphism?

Comment: Ah yes, otherwise two monoidal functors don't compose to a monoidal functor, right? Sorry, in that case I'm not sure what my question is. What is a suitable definition of image factorisation in 2-categories? I probably mean strict monoidal then.

Comment: @NoahSnyder, so I guess I'm fine with strict monoidal spherical categories, those should form a category, right?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is true, and what I was looking for.

A tensor functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is called *dominant* (sometimes called "surjective") if for any $Y: \mathcal{D}$, there is an $X: \mathcal{C}$ such that $Y$ is a subobject of $FX$.

*Theorem: Any tensor functor of fusion categories factors as a dominant functor and a full inclusion.*

Proof: First, define the category $\operatorname{Im}F$. Its objects are all objects of $\mathcal{D}$ that are isomorphic to a subobject of an $FX$, where $X$ is any object of $\mathcal{C}$. The morphisms of $\operatorname{Im}F$ are such that it is a full subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$.

By construction, $F$ restricted to $\operatorname{Im}F$ is dominant. Also $\operatorname{Im}F$ is a full subcategory, so it inherits all additional structure like the pivotal/spherical structure, a braiding or a ribbon structure.

Comment: Does anyone know a reference for this?